# Map/graph not appearing when training on darknet?

Tags: yolo, darknet

I am currently training on Darknet YOLO using AlexeyAB's version for linux on the master branch (https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) and the map/graph does not appear in a second, separate window.

My makefile is original except that I changed GPU = 1. 
I configured my .cfg, .data, .names and weights files and I am able to successfully train on 2000 iterations, however, the map/graph does not appear when I begin training and as a result, I have to take screenshots of my terminal every now-and-then to make sure training is going well.

Here is the command I use to train:

```
$ ./darknet detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg darknet53.conv.74
```

I have tried adding the `-map` flag to the end as so:

```
$ ./darknet detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg darknet53.conv.74 -map
```

but it still does not appear. Am I missing something in my command or in my config?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yolo saves graph file as 'chart.png' for every 1000 iterations. So wait for training to complete and then check your chart.png file.

Comment: Were you doing it on cloud? If yes, it's not possible to see the chart.

Comment: is it resolved now? please share what has worked in your case

Answer (score 1):

In yolov4 you can view the training graph by adding the argument -mjpeg_port 8040 (assign your port). Using your default browser, you can now view a static graph on using your http://ipaddress:8040.

Answer (score 0):

The chart should appear after the first 1000 iterations. However, this may not be the case if you set you max_batches > 10000. This is because the weights are no longer saved at the 1000 iteration intervals.
Please double check your max_batches setting and also try waiting for 1000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the chart.png you expect to see when you use `-map` will only be created if you also build Darknet with OpenCV.  In your question above (several years ago now, sorry!) you state the only change you made to `Makefile` was for the GPU.  Thus, you don't have OpenCV, and therefore you won't have `-map` nor the chart.png output.

For anyone else coming across this old question, note that repo has been abandoned for several years now.  The new repo requires OpenCV, so this is no longer an issue.

You can find the new repo with the Windows and Linux build steps documented here:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents